# filtering pandas dataframe with and without using .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple question regarding the concept of filtering a dataframe. suppose I have the below dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': [4, 5, 6, 7],'BBB': [10, 20, 30, 40],'CCC': [100, 50, -30, -50]})
```

[image: df]

I would like to perform some modifications on it base on some conditions.
If I run the below code I get my desired row:

> Method a

```
df[(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10)]
```

[image: a]

I can also get that row with the below code:

> Method b

```
df.loc[(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10)]
```

[image: b]

Both of Method a and Method b, resulted in pandas dataframe.
However when I want to modify column "CCC" based on those conditions, I get error with the "Method a":

> Method a

```
df[(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10), 'CCC'] = -1
```

> 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
>
> Method b

```
df.loc[(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10), 'CCC'] = -1
```

[image: b-1]

Comment: Use `df['CCC'][(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10)] = -1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If need set new values by mask and also by column name, [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is always necessary, because selecting column name, here `CCC`:

```
df.loc[(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10), 'CCC'] = -1
print (df)
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0    4   10   -1
1    5   20   50
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50
```

If need set multiple columns use `loc` and list of columns names:

```
df.loc[(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10), ['CCC', 'AAA']] = -1
print (df)
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0   -1   10   -1
1    5   20   50
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50
```

But if need to set all columns remove `loc` and also column name:

```
df[(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10)] = -1
print (df)
   AAA  BBB  CCC
0   -1   -1   -1
1    5   20   50
2    6   30  -30
3    7   40  -50
```

EDIT:

Solution from comment working:

```
df['CCC'][(df.AAA <= 5) & (df.BBB <= 10)] = -1
```

but not recommended, because this code lead to possible [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters) .